# XCode translate matrix ala ActionScript?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

I am wondering if there is a way to translate the underlying matrix of a layer much like you can in ActionScript3.

In AS3 I can get the transform of a layer and shift it to, let's say, make the center of the layer the anchor point, rather than the upper-left corner.

The reason I ask is because I am trying to rotate a layer (containing a square) along a diagonal axis.  I thought it might be easy if I could rotate the matrix by 45 degrees, then I could just rotate around the X-axis and be done.

But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Any help, greatly appreciate, as always.

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html).

Edit:

I am afraid I don't know what you mean by "rotating an object along a diagonal axis". What you most likely need to do is to concatenate two or more transforms.

See [figure 5-8 in Quartz 2D programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW2) The concatenation of two transforms creates the appearance of the image rotating around its lower left corner.

Comment: Hey there,

Yes, I understand that that is the method to use, but HOW do I use it.  When I do AffineTransformMakeRotation, it rotates the layer so that instead of having a square I get a diamond.

What I am looking for is a way to rotate the underlying coordinate system so that the X-axis goes from -X,+Y to +X,-Y, but the layer does not rotate.

Is that possible?  Would it work for what I am trying to do?  Or is there an even easier/better way of rotating an object along a diagonal axis?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Thanks, TZ.  That helps.  I was able to get what I wanted with this bit of code:


CATransform3DConcat(((FlippingLayerTestView *)[self view]).lyr.transform, CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, M_PI/2, -1, 1, 0));